# Linking between pages doesnt work HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hello everyone i have a problem with linking with html pages with each other i have the following code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="Test.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.HTML">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="product.HTML">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="account.HTML">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="FAQ.HTML">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="Aboutus.HTML">About US</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.HTML">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The moment i click one menu item it opens but the moment i click the second one it shows this in the url

```
file:///C:/Users/Desktop/PROJECT%20WEBSITE/FAQ.HTML#
```

It ads an # at the end and doesnt open the next page can someone help me

Comment: which all href are working

Comment: Post your `CSS` or `javascript` that has impact on the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` and it's child `<li>` elements for us to help you better.

Comment: Try adding your BASE URL to the beginning of the page files i.e: /filename/contact.html

Comment: Every href is working if I run click a button (on my menu) on my site, it wouldn't react to it. I do not understand why?

Comment: @Ivan86 Don't use javascript

Comment: @Brian every html page is in the same folder

Comment: Is it `index.html` or `index.HTML`? Check your file names and update your code

Comment: @bulutsebo Post more of your code or we might not be able to help you. The question is too broad otherwise. Post an example that we can try out and give a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do the other files contain the same or a similar looking version of your navigation code? example:

index.html contains

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
  <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
</ul>
```

product.html contains:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice how they each contain their own unique navigation code. U must take to mind that when you navigate to another html file only the code written inside that file while be used by the browser.

Comment: Ok, to be of more help is it possible that you post a image of your folder structure with the file names?